# MacBook Pro cannot install Ubuntu, ACPI

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, macbook, acpi

I am desperately trying to find help because I need Ubuntu to finish my thesis and I cannot work this out. I have tried my own things for a week, formatted my mac for a clean install etc. Also bought an external SSD to try installing there.

I am having this issue which I have not found any solution for online. 
Basically, I cannot seem to install Ubuntu 16 or 18 (latest available LTS versions) on my Late 2016 MacBook Pro with touchbar, because the installer freezes. Both in the try without installing and install Ubuntu options. 
I managed to install to an external SSD after 15 tries, but apart from not being able to boot in it now even with SIP disabled and rEFInd installed, when I was able to boot inside there (previously, before formatting), it would freeze in two minutes.

I tried 2 different USB drives (8 and 16 GB, new) and flashed the .iso with balenaEtcher and UNetBootin. Nothing...

At start up, these lines flash for 2 seconds, I was able to take a picture and have transcribed it here:

```
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)

[0.165454] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU4.PDC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)

[0.165454] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.OSCP]

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psargs-330)

[0.165454] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU5.GCAP due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)

[0.165454] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU5.PDC due to previous error

(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
```

Then the error repeats in the same way and CPU5.GCAP and CPU5.PDC become CPU6 and CPU7.

Lastly, the code ends with:

```
[6.778428] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.UA00

[6.778432] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.UA01

[6.778434] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.UA02
```

I really hope someone can give me a hint!

Best regards, stay safe during these days.

Neri

Comment: Try using some of the many acpi kernel parameters, starting with acpi=off to see if that allows things to work in a limited fashion (like using only one cpu core).  google for acpi kernel parameters to see the whole list. search for other results with your specific model mac.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I think I found the solution:

1. disable disk encryption on the internal SSD;
2. permanently set `nomodeset` inside the grub boot file.

1) guid on apple support, 2) guide on youtube.

I would suggest not closing the thread because other freezes might come up with more usage of the OS and it might not be solved yet.

Note: I have not tried *acpi=off* because I read it can cause bad issues like fans not working anymore and therefore overheating.